# Ломается задний фон и элементы сайта при изменении окна viewport

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой главный блок сайта : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При ширине viewport 1440px блок выглядит нормально , но если начать заходить в ширину ~800px начинает появлятся огромная белая полоса справа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно чем ниже разрешение тем больше эта самая полоса.

```css
body {
  font-family: Manrope;
  background: #F8F8F8;
}

.container {
  width: 1291px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header_container {
  width: 1301px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.intro {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.container-intro {
  width: 1172px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  padding-top: 191px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start;
}

.catalog-container {
  width: 1190px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-logo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header_container ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header_container ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.header_container ul li {
  margin-right: 31px;
}

.header_container ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.header_btn {
  display: flex;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 221px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #FFF;
}

.header_btn svg {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.bgmain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
}

.intro {
  min-height: 750px;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 27px;
}

.header_contact {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-links a {
  margin-right: 70px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: -0.15px;
}

.intro-main h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 53px;
  letter-spacing: -0.42px;
  width: 599px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.greentext {
  color: #00E1A9;
}

.intro-main p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 33px;
  width: 531px;
  margin-bottom: 44px;
}

.intro-btns {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro-btns a:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  width: 170px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.intro-btns a:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 227px;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.intro-btns a:nth-child(2) svg {
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.intro-btns a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

.intro-btns a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.intro-main {
  width: 599px;
}

.intro-bg-people {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 802px;
}

.intro-info h3 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 53px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}

.intro-info p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: -0.26px;
}

.intro-info span {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.intro-info {
  width: 275px;
  position: relative;
  top: 43px;
}

.catalog-item {
  width: 570px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 39px 0px 42px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
}

.catalog-item-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.catalog-item-info img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.catalog-item-info h3 {
  color: #252835;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 35px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}

.catalog-item-info p {
  color: #252835;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: -0.13px;
}

.catalog-title {
  color: #252835;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 55px;
  letter-spacing: -0.42px;
  margin-bottom: 68px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@400;500;600;700;800&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    -->
  <title>LockerBox</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="static/img/logo.png">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="header_container">
      <svg class="header-logo" width="130" height="22" viewBox="0 0 130 22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g clip-path="url(#clip0_37_200)">
                <path d="M37.7175 2.72206C38.3181 2.72217 38.9129 2.83701 39.4688 3.06017C40.0209 3.27408 40.5322 3.57829 40.9808 3.95988L41.3077 4.24068L43.3217 2.32664L42.9948 2.01719C42.3104 1.36774 41.5006 0.8592 40.613 0.521487C38.7172 -0.191127 36.6169 -0.1727 34.7344 0.573062C33.8244 0.935996 32.9999 1.4782 32.3118 2.16619C31.6244 2.86327 31.0812 3.68452 30.7122 4.58452C30.3152 5.55517 30.1169 6.59307 30.1285 7.63896C30.1163 8.68491 30.3147 9.72293 30.7122 10.6934C31.0811 11.5935 31.6243 12.4148 32.3118 13.1117C32.9999 13.7997 33.8244 14.3419 34.7344 14.7049C36.6169 15.4506 38.7172 15.4691 40.613 14.7564C41.5006 14.4187 42.3104 13.9102 42.9948 13.2607L43.3217 12.9513L41.3018 11.0258L40.9749 11.318C40.5379 11.7062 40.0338 12.0148 39.4863 12.2292C38.9277 12.4413 38.3339 12.5501 37.735 12.5501C37.1296 12.5738 36.5268 12.4606 35.9731 12.2191C35.4194 11.9776 34.9297 11.6144 34.5418 11.1576C33.6938 10.1749 33.2431 8.92071 33.275 7.63323C33.2391 6.35084 33.6812 5.09967 34.5184 4.11461C34.9078 3.65797 35.3986 3.29501 35.9532 3.05361C36.5078 2.81221 37.1113 2.69879 37.7175 2.72206Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M58.0855 0H54.3785L49.8601 6.01146H48.4007V0H45.3242V15.2722H48.4007V8.7851H49.9243L54.9214 15.2722H58.8677L52.5338 7.20344L58.0855 0Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M62.8255 8.84814H66.4624V6.05731H62.8255V2.79083H70.3153V0H59.7549V15.2722H70.3737V12.4814H62.8255V8.84814Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M82.9422 7.19198C83.4641 6.46974 83.7474 5.60754 83.7537 4.72206C83.7563 4.10946 83.6355 3.5024 83.398 2.93587C83.1606 2.36934 82.8112 1.85456 82.3701 1.4212C81.4478 0.475645 80.0701 0 78.2779 0H72.6328V15.2722H75.7034V9.48424H78.0385L82.0724 15.2722H85.8144L81.0858 8.73352C81.8298 8.38553 82.4693 7.85446 82.9422 7.19198ZM75.7034 2.76791H77.986C78.6706 2.75047 79.3425 2.95156 79.9008 3.34097C80.1281 3.50219 80.3108 3.71667 80.4321 3.9649C80.5535 4.21312 80.6096 4.48721 80.5955 4.76218C80.6107 5.0373 80.555 5.31174 80.4336 5.56015C80.3122 5.80856 80.1289 6.0229 79.9008 6.18338C79.3437 6.57507 78.671 6.7764 77.986 6.75645H75.7034V2.76791Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M96.0768 6.72779C96.3204 6.48802 96.5286 6.21605 96.6956 5.91976C97.0292 5.34985 97.2025 4.70312 97.1976 4.04584C97.1702 3.00653 96.7328 2.01829 95.9776 1.28939C95.5181 0.845913 94.9689 0.50201 94.3656 0.279907C93.7623 0.0578045 93.1182 -0.0375547 92.4749 -7.25629e-06H87.04V15.2722H93.3506C94.0493 15.3023 94.7472 15.1968 95.4043 14.9618C96.0615 14.7268 96.6649 14.3668 97.1801 13.9026C97.6401 13.4939 98.0076 12.9951 98.2589 12.4384C98.5103 11.8817 98.64 11.2794 98.6396 10.6705C98.6705 9.66976 98.3256 8.69279 97.6705 7.92549C97.2318 7.41981 96.6886 7.01153 96.0768 6.72779V6.72779ZM93.5316 5.58165C93.1356 5.88975 92.6413 6.05015 92.1364 6.03438H90.1107V2.72779H92.1364C92.6424 2.7111 93.1377 2.87384 93.5316 3.18624C93.7099 3.32817 93.8512 3.50985 93.9436 3.71618C94.036 3.92251 94.0769 4.14752 94.0628 4.37249C94.0759 4.59734 94.0346 4.82204 93.9423 5.02822C93.8499 5.23439 93.7092 5.41619 93.5316 5.55873V5.58165ZM90.1107 8.66475H93.0821C93.718 8.63612 94.3421 8.84035 94.8334 9.23782C95.0416 9.41083 95.2067 9.62836 95.316 9.87372C95.4252 10.1191 95.4758 10.3858 95.4638 10.6533C95.474 10.9164 95.4224 11.1783 95.3131 11.4187C95.2037 11.6592 95.0396 11.8718 94.8334 12.0401C94.3435 12.44 93.7184 12.6446 93.0821 12.6132H90.1107V8.66475Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M115.003 4.58452C114.628 3.68253 114.073 2.8631 113.372 2.17426C112.67 1.48542 111.835 0.941047 110.916 0.573059C109.002 -0.183563 106.864 -0.183563 104.95 0.573059C104.031 0.940489 103.196 1.48466 102.494 2.17357C101.792 2.86248 101.238 3.6822 100.864 4.58452C100.464 5.55422 100.265 6.59277 100.28 7.63896C100.265 8.68701 100.464 9.72743 100.864 10.6991C101.243 11.6021 101.798 12.4236 102.498 13.1175C103.196 13.8003 104.026 14.3399 104.939 14.7049C106.851 15.4687 108.992 15.4687 110.905 14.7049C111.816 14.3398 112.643 13.8002 113.339 13.1175C114.039 12.4236 114.594 11.6021 114.974 10.6991C115.374 9.72738 115.572 8.68699 115.557 7.63896C115.581 6.59476 115.392 5.5564 115.003 4.58452ZM112.446 7.63896C112.489 8.93257 112.034 10.1947 111.173 11.1748C110.762 11.6072 110.265 11.9521 109.713 12.1879C109.161 12.4236 108.565 12.5453 107.963 12.5453C107.36 12.5453 106.764 12.4236 106.212 12.1879C105.66 11.9521 105.163 11.6072 104.752 11.1748C103.886 10.1973 103.429 8.93386 103.473 7.63896C103.426 6.34717 103.884 5.08653 104.752 4.11461C105.161 3.67987 105.658 3.33297 106.21 3.09571C106.763 2.85846 107.359 2.73598 107.963 2.73598C108.566 2.73598 109.162 2.85846 109.715 3.09571C110.267 3.33297 110.764 3.67987 111.173 4.11461C112.042 5.08453 112.503 6.34222 112.463 7.63323L112.446 7.63896Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M124.542 7.48997L129.86 0H126.264L122.773 5.14613L119.276 0H115.517L120.829 7.53009L115.277 15.2722H118.897L122.563 9.851L126.287 15.2722H130L124.542 7.48997Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M5.87274 0H0V2.79083H2.86632V12.4814V15.2722H11.4711V12.4814H5.87274V0Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M27.577 4.58452C27.2027 3.6822 26.6483 2.86248 25.9465 2.17357C25.2448 1.48466 24.4097 0.940488 23.4906 0.573057C21.5731 -0.186645 19.4302 -0.186645 17.5127 0.573057C16.5939 0.941046 15.7592 1.48542 15.0575 2.17426C14.3557 2.8631 13.8012 3.68253 13.4263 4.58452C13.0262 5.55427 12.8277 6.59279 12.8426 7.63896C12.8277 8.68699 13.0262 9.72738 13.4263 10.6991C13.8042 11.6011 14.3596 12.421 15.0609 13.1117C15.7622 13.7961 16.5958 14.3358 17.5127 14.6991C19.4253 15.463 21.5663 15.463 23.4789 14.6991C24.3919 14.3322 25.2213 13.7907 25.919 13.106C26.6203 12.4152 27.1758 11.5954 27.5536 10.6934C27.9533 9.72152 28.1517 8.68122 28.1374 7.63323C28.159 6.59051 27.9685 5.55404 27.577 4.58452ZM25.0142 7.63896C25.0586 8.93181 24.6064 10.1938 23.7474 11.1748C23.3477 11.6256 22.8504 11.9831 22.2918 12.2211C21.7333 12.459 21.1276 12.5715 20.5192 12.5501C19.9126 12.5697 19.3092 12.4565 18.7529 12.2186C18.1965 11.9807 17.7011 11.6241 17.3026 11.1748C16.4394 10.1955 15.983 8.93333 16.0241 7.63896C15.9801 6.34762 16.4371 5.08801 17.3026 4.1146C17.6999 3.66319 18.1949 3.30446 18.7513 3.06455C19.3078 2.82464 19.9117 2.70959 20.5192 2.72778C21.1286 2.70787 21.7348 2.82208 22.2934 3.06205C22.852 3.30202 23.3488 3.66166 23.7474 4.1146C24.6058 5.08914 25.0582 6.34563 25.0142 7.63323V7.63896Z" fill="white"/>
                <path d="M29.9768 19.914C30.3878 19.5297 30.7647 19.1117 31.1035 18.6647C31.3818 18.2735 31.5287 17.8067 31.5238 17.3295C31.5294 16.7967 31.3195 16.2835 30.9401 15.9026C30.708 15.685 30.4326 15.5167 30.1313 15.4083C29.83 15.2998 29.5091 15.2535 29.1888 15.2722C28.7035 15.2674 28.2244 15.3795 27.7935 15.5988C27.4444 15.7694 27.1268 15.996 26.8537 16.2693L26.6318 16.4986L27.6476 17.49L27.8753 17.2837C28.0532 17.128 28.2491 16.9934 28.459 16.8825C28.6819 16.7666 28.9308 16.7075 29.1829 16.7106C29.3956 16.7006 29.6043 16.7702 29.7667 16.9054C29.8382 16.9635 29.8945 17.0375 29.9311 17.1212C29.9676 17.2049 29.9833 17.296 29.9768 17.3868C29.9644 17.6249 29.8767 17.8533 29.7258 18.0401C29.3841 18.4777 29.0095 18.8896 28.605 19.2722L26.9704 20.8653V22.0115H31.6406V20.5788H29.3055L29.9768 19.914Z" fill="white"/>
                </g>
                <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip0_37_200">
                <rect width="130" height="22" fill="white"/>
                </clipPath>
                </defs>
                </svg>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Платы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Калькулятор</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Клиенты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header_contact">
        <div class="header-links">
          <a class="header_mail" href="mailto:info@lockerbox.ru">info@lockerbox.ru</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="header_btn" href="#"><svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <g clip-path="url(#clip0_60_151)">
                        <path d="M16.5789 11.8516C15.4686 11.8516 14.3811 11.6782 13.3503 11.3381C12.8473 11.1647 12.276 11.2983 11.9454 11.6356L9.9019 13.1789C7.55716 11.9274 6.05653 10.4277 4.82212 8.10001L6.32369 6.10485C6.70169 5.72685 6.83718 5.17357 6.67518 4.65537C6.33222 3.618 6.15791 2.52948 6.15791 1.42105C6.15791 0.637565 5.52035 0 4.73686 0H1.42105C0.637565 0 0 0.637565 0 1.42105C0 10.5622 7.4378 18 16.5789 18C17.3624 18 18 17.3624 18 16.5789V13.2726C18 12.4892 17.3624 11.8516 16.5789 11.8516Z" fill="#00E1A9"/>
                        </g>
                        <defs>
                        <clipPath id="clip0_60_151">
                        <rect width="18" height="18" fill="white"/>
                        </clipPath>
                        </defs>
                        </svg>
                        Заказать звонок</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="intro">
    <img class="bgmain" src="static/img/introbg.png" alt="">
    <img class="intro-bg-people" src="static/img/intropeople.png" alt="">
    <div class="container-intro">
      <div class="intro-main">
        <h1>Поставка комплексных контроллеров и электронных замков <br>
          <span class="greentext">для систем хранения</span></h1>
        <p>5 лет мы занимается полным циклом производства автоматизированных систем хранения</p>
        <div class="intro-btns">
          <a class="intro-btn" href="#">В каталог</a>
          <a class="intro-btn" href="#"><svg width="21" height="21" viewBox="0 0 21 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M16.2795 0H4.72042C3.60648 0 2.7002 0.906281 2.7002 2.02022V18.9798C2.7002 20.0937 3.60648 21 4.72042 21H16.2795C17.3935 21 18.2997 20.0937 18.2997 18.9798V2.02022C18.2997 0.906281 17.3935 0 16.2795 0ZM5.46912 3.49027C5.46912 3.15049 5.74458 2.87503 6.08435 2.87503H14.9156C15.2553 2.87503 15.5308 3.15049 15.5308 3.49027V4.70507C15.5308 5.04484 15.2553 5.3203 14.9156 5.3203H6.08435C5.74458 5.3203 5.46912 5.04484 5.46912 4.70507V3.49027ZM7.54045 17.3051C7.54045 17.6449 7.26499 17.9204 6.92521 17.9204H6.08439C5.74462 17.9204 5.46916 17.6449 5.46916 17.3051V16.7222C5.46916 16.3825 5.74462 16.107 6.08439 16.107H6.92521C7.26499 16.107 7.54045 16.3825 7.54045 16.7222V17.3051ZM7.54045 13.6642C7.54045 14.004 7.26499 14.2794 6.92521 14.2794H6.08439C5.74462 14.2794 5.46916 14.004 5.46916 13.6642V13.0813C5.46916 12.7415 5.74462 12.466 6.08439 12.466H6.92521C7.26499 12.466 7.54045 12.7415 7.54045 13.0813V13.6642ZM11.586 17.3051C11.586 17.6449 11.3106 17.9204 10.9708 17.9204H10.13C9.79016 17.9204 9.51474 17.6449 9.51474 17.3051V16.7222C9.51474 16.3825 9.79016 16.107 10.13 16.107H10.9708C11.3106 16.107 11.586 16.3825 11.586 16.7222V17.3051ZM11.586 13.6642C11.586 14.004 11.3106 14.2794 10.9708 14.2794H10.13C9.79016 14.2794 9.51474 14.004 9.51474 13.6642V13.0813C9.51474 12.7415 9.79016 12.466 10.13 12.466H10.9708C11.3106 12.466 11.586 12.7415 11.586 13.0813V13.6642ZM11.586 10.0232C11.586 10.363 11.3106 10.6384 10.9708 10.6384H6.08435C5.74458 10.6384 5.46912 10.363 5.46912 10.0232V9.44028C5.46912 9.10051 5.74458 8.82504 6.08435 8.82504H10.9708C11.3106 8.82504 11.586 9.10051 11.586 9.44028V10.0232ZM15.6316 17.3051C15.6316 17.6449 15.3561 17.9204 15.0164 17.9204H14.1755C13.8358 17.9204 13.5603 17.6449 13.5603 17.3051V16.7222C13.5603 16.3825 13.8358 16.107 14.1755 16.107H15.0164C15.3561 16.107 15.6316 16.3825 15.6316 16.7222V17.3051ZM15.6316 13.6642C15.6316 14.004 15.3561 14.2794 15.0164 14.2794H14.1755C13.8358 14.2794 13.5603 14.004 13.5603 13.6642V13.0813C13.5603 12.7415 13.8358 12.466 14.1755 12.466H15.0164C15.3561 12.466 15.6316 12.7415 15.6316 13.0813V13.6642ZM15.6316 10.0232C15.6316 10.363 15.3561 10.6384 15.0164 10.6384H14.1755C13.8358 10.6384 13.5603 10.363 13.5603 10.0232V9.44028C13.5603 9.10051 13.8358 8.82504 14.1755 8.82504H15.0164C15.3561 8.82504 15.6316 9.10051 15.6316 9.44028V10.0232Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                        Сделать расчет
                        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="intro-info">
        <h3>10 000+</h3>
        <p>ячеек и замков</p>
        <span>установлено нами в России<br> за 5 лет</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="catalog">
    <div class="catalog-container">
      <h2 class="catalog-title">Каталог обрудования</h2>
      <div class="catalog-blocks">
        <div class="catalog-item">
          <div class="catalog-item-info">
            <img src="static/img/slave8.png" alt="">
            <h3>Плата Slave8</h3>
            <p>Плата Slave8 способная управлять до 8-мью замками с возможностью подключения датчиков открытия/закрытия замка</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так правильно, у вас всё жёсткими размерами в px написано. Читайте про адаптивную вёрстку. полоса вылезает из-за элемента `.header`, т.к. он не даёт `body` сжаться.

Comment: Если в адаптивную вёрстку страшно погружаться, можно как в tilda zero block сделать несколько вариантов под разную ширину.

Comment: ну тут надо делать адаптив. ну или попробуй к ```width``` ```max-width```